# Could we add a Candidate Score viewer to our profiles?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, election

Either as a rep privilege or perhaps implemented for any user profile, allowing a user to see themselves and how much their score reflects how much they've been contributing to the community.

[image]

Referencing this thread that details how to get the [Candidate Score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/252641/what-are-the-details-on-the-candidate-score-which-shows-during-an-election), I assume most people on this site do this out of goodwill, just like the moderators do. SE is a user-driven site, and the moderators are all mostly volunteers who spend time and effort doing a nearly thankless job for free. As such, I do believe users are in general willing to look for how they can change in order to contribute to the community even more. I know I'm severely lacking in many areas on some sites and aim to change that, no matter how long it could take.

Adding a candidate score section or something of the sort to our profile pages could be a great way for people who aspire to be moderators but know they aren't quite there yet, just like myself. It would be a great way to understand where we lack and where we exceed and excel as community members and I think this feature would greatly aide in that.

The way the current badge tracker is great -- it sets goals for the next badge. But imagine we could have a "candidate score" tracker that would allow us to see how we weigh up against an "ideal" moderator candidate, and allow us to improve from there.

Comment: I'm not sure how much this matters... it's only relevant when a site is in an election... and most users have no interest in being mods.

Comment: @Catija What about users who simply want to make an impact on this site and contribute but are not sure what they lack or where they stand?  I know for sure I'd welcome such an idea because I like contributing to the site, but I don't know how I could improve on.  It doesn't even have to say "Candidate score", maybe "Community member" or something along the lines.