# Show users their candidate score before self-nominating to a moderator election?

Tags: feature-request, election, nominations, candidate-score

A number of the candidates in the ongoing [Travel.SE election](https://travel.stackexchange.com/election) indicated that a primary reason for self-nominating was to see their [moderator candidate score](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/252641/287315).  This forced a primary stage and perhaps increased the candidate pool with people who would not likely be dedicated enough or know the community well enough to do a good job.  There is a [Data Explorer query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/queries?order_by=popular&q=candidate%20score) around somewhere that lets people see their moderator score but this might not be widely known or easy to find.

Can we show that to a user on the page before they self-nominate?  Then there won't be self-nominations from folks who primarily want to see what their score is.

Answer (score 5):

While there's not an *official* way to see your candidate score, either on the [Elections.SE](http://elections.stackexchange.com) site, or on the `/election` page of each sub site, you can use [a SEDE query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/298418/candidate-score) to find out your candidate score.

You just put in your UserId (or UserIds, it supports multiple people), found in the URL of your user profile, and you can see the score/s.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned the existence of an SEDE query but am requesting a new feature that the result of this query automatically get printed somewhere on the page with the nomination form.

Comment: `elections.stackexchange.com`, is that a valid site?