# Horizontal line appears under posts that have deleted comments

Tags: bug, comments, design

It appears that a recent update has introduced a design flaw: on posts that have had comments that have *all* been deleted, a gray horizontal line appears above the "add comment" button a few seconds after it loads. Here's [an example post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277837/show-users-their-candidate-score-before-self-nominating-to-a-moderator-election):

> [image: Line above "add comment"]

But on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/333674/pluralization-issue-returns-on-new-question-statistics-underneath-title-with-vi), which (to my knowledge) has never had *any* comments posted on it before, not even deleted ones, doesn't show such a horizontal line.

While it probably *is* a good idea to indicate publicly that comments have been posted on the post, but have all been deleted, I think this line is probably an unintentional design bug. Also, in my opinion, any such intentional indicator should be *much* more conspicuous.

Reproduced under both Internet Explorer 11 and Chrome on Windows 8.1.

**Update:** This appears to happen only when following a link to a deleted *comment*, not when following a link to the post itself. When following a link to a deleted comment on a post that has had all its comments removed, the line is visible; otherwise, when following a link to the post itself, it's not. The line appears a few seconds after the post has loaded.

Comment: No repro in Chrome / Win 10: This is what I see, no user scripts running https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Di0q.png

Comment: But *very faint* lines appear under *all* posts, in firefox at least.

Comment: I see a line under the Q of neither question. FF on Mac. I do see a line under the answer of the first question, where there are comments. Also on this question I see a line, since there are comments.

Comment: Using Chrome, 78.0.3904.70, on a MacBook, OS X Yosemite, no line appears when I view the page.

Comment: Please indicate the operating system you are using, which browser and its version.

Comment: I reproduced it in an answer to this question. Opened a link to a deleted comment to my answer and saw the line. Very unlikely that this happens often but should probably fix it nonetheless.

Comment: Just noticed this again following the comment link of this question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/349903/should-comments-like-i-love-this-post-be-flagged. From inspecting the HTML in Chrome dev tools, it looks like a `dno` class is added to the comment container for each post if there are no comments. But this class is removed when following a link to a comment. That's what causes the border to show. It looks like `dno` causes the `display:none` css rule to apply.